# Is it possible to develop GCC plugins for the linker?

Tags: gcc, plugins, linker, register-transfer-level

I am working on a **GCC plugin for inserting custom assembly instructions at specific positions** of each function, e.g. at the very beginning or right before return statements. The plugin is registered to be executed during the RTL passes and works just fine in principle.

Now my problem is that using this approach I can only instrument programs where I have the full source code available, i.e. no libraries, because those are only linked into the application and not compiled by me (this is only about static linking; dynamic linking is a different topic).

**Is there a way to perform optimization at linker level** using a custom plugin, similarly to what I am doing at compiler level? I know that certain optimizations take place during linking, but I could not find any resources on the question if/how what I want to do is possible at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities to optimize at linker level:
The first one is the lto. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization. In this case, it will be an rtl pass which will be called on one module.
The second option is to use linker relaxation if is supported for your target. Based on the relaxation information you can insert or delete instructions

Comment: Thank you! -flto is already enabled, but how do I register my plugin for a pass during linking? It is not executed when I simply use -fplugin=.. and plugin_init is never called here. I am compiling for RISC-V with riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc btw.

Comment: how did you called your plugin? can you give the exact command line please.

Comment: The exact command is `/opt/riscv/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv32imfcxpulpv2 -mfdiv -D__riscv__ -MMD -MP -flto -O -g -fplugin=gcc_plugin.so -o <out path> <list of object files> -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--gc-sections -L/<path>/rules -Tpulpissimo/link.ld -L/<path>/pulpissimo -L/<path>/pulpissimo_genesys2 -lrt -lrtio -lrt -lgcc`

Comment: (Building with the PULP SDK in order to run on a RISC-V PULPissimo SoC)

Comment: At first sight , i don't see anythings strange. How did you created your plugin. To test, I created a plugin which is equivalent to hello world, it works fine with the  riscv toolchain  from (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain) and i see that the init function is called after lto1 too.

Comment: I was missing the the `-flto` when compiling the object files, I had only added it to the final step. It is working now!